# Can't pickle <function Layer.add_loss.<locals>._tag_callable at 0x7fd4045f55e0>:

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Full error:

> Can't pickle <function Layer.add_loss.._tag_callable at 0x7fd4045f55e0>: it's not found as tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer.Layer.add_loss.._tag_callable

I am trying to train this neural network using code that was written for tensorflow 1 but I cannot pickle the model with my virtual env using tensorflow 2. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Thanks!